# React based form fields are not Visible to Selenium, although it is available in DOM

Tags: c#, reactjs, selenium

There are a few React based a form element in this webpage and I am getting OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException for Password field, when I wait until it is available, although it is present in the DOM. Please find the code I wrote in C# using Selenium:

```
var Driver = new ChromeDriver();
Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
Driver.Url = @"https://www.crownbet.com.au";

//Opens the login flyout
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(@class,'login-flyout-button__title') and contains(text(),'LOGIN')]")).Click();

//Defining Wait
var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));

//Waiting for Username Field
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Name("username")));
//Entering Username
Driver.FindElement(By.Name("username")).SendKeys("username");

//Waiting for Password Field- THIS FAILS, ALTHOUGH FIELD IS VISIBLE.
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Name("password")));
//Entering Password
Driver.FindElement(By.Name("password")).SendKeys("password");

Driver.Quit();
```

> wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Name("password")))
>   is throwing WebDriverTimeoutException. Can someone suggest, how to
>   handle this ReactJS form?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points:

1. The `Username` field and the `Password` field renders at the same time. So once we wait for the `Username` field, we don't need to wait for the `Password` field individually anymore.
2. Instead of using the `ElementIsVisible` clause we can use `ElementToBeClickable` clause.
3. Instead of using the `name` locator, we will use an unique logical `xpath`.
4. Your code block will be :

   ```
   var Driver = new ChromeDriver();
   Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
   Driver.Url = @"https://www.crownbet.com.au";
   //Opens the login flyout
   Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(@class,'login-flyout-button__title') and contains(text(),'LOGIN')]")).Click();
   //Defining Wait
   var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
   //Waiting for Username & Password Field
   wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//input[@name='username']")));
   //Entering Username
   Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@name='username']")).SendKeys("username");
   //Entering Password
   Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@name='password']")).SendKeys("password");
   Driver.Quit();
   ```